# $('') selector not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How come variables such as `img : $('img')` in my function are losing their value after an ajax call. Here is an example function.

```
imageFades: {
   img : $('img'),

   init: function() {
      this.img.fadeIn(200)
      console.log('fire')
   }
}
```

After the ajax call the console.log fires, but the fadeIn does not. I've tested directly adding `$('img').fadeIn(200)` to the init function and that works fine. What is exactly going on?

Comment: Why not post the entire function, including the ajax, if that's the problem ?

Comment: Anyway, the issue is probably that the images are gotten when the object literal is created, and it gets whatever images are in the DOM at that time, not images added later.

Comment: I've isolated the problem down to the variables losing their value, there are no issues with the function.

Comment: Ah I see.. Is there a way to re create the objects after the call?

Comment: Yes, you call the `$()` function again.

Comment: Is `this.img` opacity set to `0` after initial `this.img.fadeIn(200)` , `$.ajax` call ? Can post `html` , `js` ?

Comment: Don't cause a _HTML re-parse_ if you want to keep using "the same" elements across it

Answer (score 4):

If you replaced your images in the ajax call (which it sounds like) or any time after the `imageFades` object was created, then you will have to rerun the selector so that it can see the newly added images.

```
imageFades: {
   init: function() {
      $('img').fadeIn(200);
      console.log('fire')
   }
}
```

jQuery objects are not "live".  They don't keep up with changes in the DOM. They represent a snapshot of what was in the DOM at the time you created the jQuery object and that point in time that it ran the selector query.

Comment: Cheers, that makes sense. So there is no way to work around having selectors as variables?

Comment: @JayBon - jQuery objects are a snapshot of a set of DOM elements.  They don't update themselves.  There is no way around that.  If you want a current query, you have to run the query again (e.g. create a new jQuery object).  For certain types of event handling, one can work around this with delegated event handling, but that doesn't apply to this case.

Comment: @jfriend66 Okay thanks for your help. Would this be overkill then?

`imageFades: {
   img : 'img',

   init: function() {
      $(this.img).fadeIn(200)
      console.log('fire')
   }
}`

Comment: @JayBon - it would work, but I don't quite see the point unless you're going to change the `.img` property from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your entire code, but most likely you have confused the use of `this`. In a jQuery AJAX response function, `this` is not set to a created object. To quote the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings;